# Erro ao colorir gráfico de barras e legenda com a função pal.bands

Tags: r, gráfico, plot, barplot

Estou tentando reproduzir o gráfico abaixo:

[image]

No entanto, não estou conseguindo colorir o meu gráfico por meio da função pal.bands de acordo com as informações que estão na planilha abaixo:

Os dados se encontram neste link:
[Base de Dados](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZGaVrwEmLVroLfLmBDh7BWN60gtEdpr/view?usp=sharing)

As cores no qual eu estou representando na tabela acima estão definidas abaixo por e podem ser vistas no pacote pals:

[image]

Eu preciso que cada cor esteja associada as informações que estão na planilha acima, e cada uma das cores com suas siglas respectivas interiormente ao gráfico, por exemplo:

As siglas são:

```
Control 0.00 Violet
Control 0.01 Violet
Control 0.02 Violet
.
.
.
Control 0.30 Green


Violet = Vi
Violet + Blue = Vi / Bl
Blue + Green = Bl / Gr
Green = Gr
Violet + Blue + Green = Vi / Bl / Gr
```

Abaixo estão os códigos em R, todavia, não estou conseguindo colorir por meio da função pal.bands e nem inserir a legenda interior ao gráfico:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(pals)

pal.bands(cubicyf)

dados = read.table("datagraph.csv", header=T, dec=",",sep=";")
dados$Group=as.factor(dados$Group)
dados$Colors=as.factor(dados$Colors)
x <- xtabs(~Concentration + Group, data = dados)
x
x11()
barplot(x,
        beside = FALSE,
        xlab = "Concentrations dose",
        ylab = "Concentrations mol",
        col = "pal.bands(cubicyf)")
legend("Vi", "Vi/Bl","Vi/Bl/Gr","Gr/Bl","Gr")

Error in rect(y1, x1, y2, x2, ...) : 
  invalid color name 'pal.bands(cubicyf)'
> legend("Vi", "Vi/Bl","Vi/Bl/Gr","Gr/Bl","Gr")
Error in match.arg(x, c("bottomright", "bottom", "bottomleft", "left",  : 
  'arg' should be one of “bottomright”, “bottom”, “bottomleft”, “left”, “topleft”, “top”, “topright”, “right”, “center”
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, carregar os pacotes necessários e ler os dados mas desta vez vou ler com `read.csv2`, uma vez que já tem os valores de `header = TRUE`, `dec = ","` e `sep = ";"`.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(pals)

dados <- read.csv2("datagraph.csv")
dados$Group <- factor(dados$Group)
dados$Colors <- factor(dados$Colors)
```

Agora ver como estão ordenadas as cores.

```
levels(dados$Colors)
#[1] "Blue"              "Blue+Green"        "Green"            
#[4] "Violet"            "Violet+Blue"       "Violet+Blue+Green"
```

Não é esta a ordem requerida, pretende-se ter os violetas primeiro e os verdes no fim. A ordem correta será:

```
levels(dados$Colors)[c(4:6, 1:3)]
#[1] "Violet"            "Violet+Blue"       "Violet+Blue+Green"
#[4] "Blue"              "Blue+Green"        "Green"
```

É só refazer o `factor`.

```
dados$Colors <- factor(dados$Colors, 
                       levels = levels(dados$Colors)[c(4:6, 1:3)])
```

Agora, em vez de `xtabs`, vou criar um data.frame de valores de concentrações agregadas por grupo e cor.

```
agg <- aggregate(Concentration ~ Group + Colors, data = dados, sum)
```

E finalmente o gráfico.

```
n <- length(levels(agg$Colors))
clrs <- cubicyf(n)

barplot(Concentration ~ Colors + Group,
        data = agg,
        beside = FALSE,
        xlab = "Concentrations dose",
        ylab = expression(MgCl[2] ~ "[mol]"),
        col = clrs)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]